# Passing arguments form java program to bash script that call another java programa with the arguments

Tags: java, bash, parameters, arguments, escaping

I want to executing a shell scripting in my java program passing a argument showed bellow:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./test.sh " + "\\\"param1\\\"\\\"param2\\\"\\\"param3\\\"");
```

And the test.sh will call another java program passing  the string argument like this:

```
another.jar \"param1\"\"param2\"\"param3\"
```

and finally  the program anther.jar will interpret the argument in this format

```
another.jar "param1""param2""param3"
```

I'm a bit confuse with this bacause I can't deal correctly with escapes characters in this situation..kkk

I tried some strings formats in the first command but I didn't get the correct form.

Some help will be fine!

Thx!

Comment: Why do you need quotes around your arguments to begin with? Is the target .jar expecting quotes around its arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be better off using [**exec(String[] cmdarray)**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) instead of [**exec(String cmd)**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).  This is because [**exec(String cmd)**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) tokenizes the arguments via [**StringTokenizer**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), which pays no attention at all to double quotes when breaking up the command line arguments.

Try something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> argList = new ArrayList<String>();
argList.add("param1");
argList.add("param2");
argList.add("param2");
String[] args = argList.toArray(new String[argList.size()]);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mycommand", args);
```

Characters inside the param values should not need quoting or escaping, except insofar as Java source code string literals may require escaping.

Comment: I need to pass the command together with parameter in a string...but I apreciate your suggestion Mike! Thanks!

Comment: I got!  "./command.sh \"\"" +  "\\\\\\\"param_1\\\\\\\"" + 
          "\\\\\\\"param_2\\\\\\\"" + 
           "\"\"";

Answer (score 5):

Use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  Nothing special needs to be done with the parameters, they'll just trickle through.

```
//ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.sh", "param1", "param2", "param3");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.sh", "param1 " + "param2 " + "param3");
pb.start();
```

In test.sh:

```
java -jar program2 $1 # Or however you want to call it.
```

In program2.java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thans so much Jonathon. But I'm not able to change the way of the sh program or the other java app receive the argument. Is only one argument should be tranfered. Thx

Comment: @Bera I updated the answer -- what happens if you try it as shown?  I would expect it to send the arguments as a single parameter.