# Best design pattern for this issue

Tags: java, command, design-patterns

I need to build various commands and pass them as arguments to another program.

The commands share some information and format but differ in the number of arguments.

For example, for a CRUD operation, I might generate the following command string:

```
"create""host_ip""database""user_id""profile""personal_data1""personal_data2""personal_datan"
"retrive""host_ip""database""user_id"
"update""host_ip""database""user_id""personal_data1""personal_data2""personal_datan"
"delete""host_ip""database""user_id"
```

I believe there are smarter ways to do this & by sharing it on this amazing site, I might do a better job.

Comment: Related to earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221444/passing-arguments-form-java-program-to-bash-script-that-call-another-java-program

Comment: Are you using any type of frameworks? Check out Spring Framework JDBC Support: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe too obvious but have you thought of the [Command Pattern?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

> In object-oriented programming, the
>   command pattern is a design pattern in
>   which an object is used to represent
>   and encapsulate all the information
>   needed to call a method at a later
>   time. This information includes the
>   method name, the object that owns the
>   method and values for the method
>   parameters. Three terms always
>   associated with the command pattern
>   are client, invoker and receiver. The
>   client instantiates the command object
>   and provides the information required
>   to call the method at a later time.
>   The invoker decides when the method
>   should be called. The receiver is an
>   instance of the class that contains
>   the method's code. Using command
>   objects makes it easier to construct
>   general components that need to
>   delegate, sequence or execute method
>   calls at a time of their choosing
>   without the need to know the owner of
>   the method or the method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a builder class that can build application commands. If there are any objects that are used between all build methods send it in through the builder constructor.

```
public class CommandBuilder() {

    public String buildCreate(..) {..}

    public String buildRetrieve(..) {..}

    public String buildUpdate(..) {..}

    public String buildDelete(..)
}
```

If you want to create more abstraction you could always return an object that simply knows how to execute said command on demand.