# Selenium Server and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to automate my selenium script by using java.
The command that I'm trying to execute is:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /javalibs/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "/tmp/googlesearchsuite.html" "/tmp/RESUTL.html"
```

That command executes perfectly on my Mac in terminal. Now I want to convert that into Java; here is the code that I'm using for that:

```
public void localRun() {

    Process p = null;

    try {

        String cmd = "/usr/bin/java -jar /javalibs/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -debug -htmlSuite \"*firefox\" \"http://www.google.com\" \"/tmp/googlesearchsuite.html\" \"/tmp/RESUTL.html\"";

        System.out.print("COMMAND: " + cmd);

        System.out.println();

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        p = runtime.exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        line = null;

        while ((line = error.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```

When I run that java code I'm getting this log with weird error message (omitting the whole log):

```
testSuite=/lensoo/googlesearchsuite.html
COMMAND: /usr/bin/java -jar /javalibs/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -debug -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "/lensoo/googlesearchsuite.html" "/lensoo/RESUTL.html"
14:49:55.619 INFO - Java: Apple Inc. 20.45-b01-451
14:49:55.620 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.8.3 x86_64
14:49:55.630 INFO - v2.32.0, with Core v2.32.0. Built from revision 6c40c18
14:49:55.631 INFO - Selenium server running in debug mode.
......
14:49:55.790 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
14:49:55.801 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
14:49:55.801 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@152c7568
May 3, 2013 2:49:49 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
Can't find HTML Suite file:/Users/maksim/IdeaProjects/CMPE287-TaaS/"/tmp/googlesearchsuite.html":
Usage: java -jar selenium-server.jar [-interactive] [options]

  -port <nnnn>: the port number the selenium server should use
    (default 4444)
  -timeout <nnnn>: an integer number of seconds we should allow a
    clie.......
```

Here is the whole message that I got: http://pastebin.com/QzHeQ0Bm

Is there any difference between executing command from command line and java? If yes then what will be the proper way to execute that command to run my Selenium HTML Suite.

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing in a String[] as a second parameter into your run.  Change that and I believe it will work.

```
String cmd ="/usr/bin/java -jar /javalibs/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar"
String[] args = {"my","-arguments","-to","pass","in"};
p = runtime.exec(cmd, args);
```

I also found this answer, [Passing arguments form java program to bash script that call another java programa with the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221444/passing-arguments-form-java-program-to-bash-script-that-call-another-java-progra). Which shows a couple of different ways of running commands.

Comment: Looks like i got it. here is how I was able to run that command:

String[] args = new String[]{"bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/java -jar /javalibs/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -debug -htmlSuite \"*firefox\" \"http://www.google.com\" \"/tmp/googlesearchsuite.html\" \"/tmp/RESUTL.html\"" };

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
p = runtime.exec(args);

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I need to use array of strings. :)